# storm-starter flux-core test failure

Tags: java, maven, apache-storm

I am trying to learn with storm-starter project and following the instructions mentioned in below link.

https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter

However when I issue mvn package command. I am getting the below error during testing of flux-core.

Any idea..?

```
 -------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running org.apache.storm.flux.multilang.MultilangEnvirontmentTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.062 sec <<< FAILURE! - in **org.apache.storm.flux.multilang.MultilangEnvirontmentTest
testInvokeNode(org.apache.storm.flux.multilang.MultilangEnvirontmentTest)  Time elapsed: 0.009 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "node": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    at org.apache.storm.flux.multilang.MultilangEnvirontmentTest.invokeCommand(MultilangEnvirontmentTest.java:80)
    at org.apache.storm.flux.multilang.MultilangEnvirontmentTest.testInvokeNode(MultilangEnvirontmentTest.java:47)**

Running org.apache.storm.flux.IntegrationTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec - in org.apache.storm.flux.IntegrationTest
Running org.apache.storm.flux.TCKTest
Tests run: 18, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.939 sec - in org.apache.storm.flux.TCKTest
Running org.apache.storm.flux.FluxBuilderTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec - in org.apache.storm.flux.FluxBuilderTest

Results :

Tests in error: 
  MultilangEnvirontmentTest.testInvokeNode:47->invokeCommand:80 » IO Cannot run ...
```